# how to simulate JTAG by SPI in zynq

Tags: c, arm, spi, jtag, zynq-ultrascale+

There is some problem in my zynq 7020, and I have to use SPI to simulate JTAG, can someone offer the code to carry out it? please, it's important for me!

there's picture that imitate the way that how to make it,but I still don't know how to make full use of it [maybe the way how to realize it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOsNB.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.